# Adding expandable bars using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to get something as shown below:

[image]

This is the data I am using

```
var student_data = [{
            category: 'Struggling',
            students: [
              'Ben',
              'Elizabeth'
            ]
        }, {
            category: 'Level One',
            students: [
              'Jessica',
              'Matt'
            ]
        },
        {
            category: 'Level Two',
            students: [
              'Luke',
              'Leia',
              'Han',
              'Chewbaca'
            ]
        },
        {
            category: 'Level Three',
            students: [
              'Obi-one',
              'Qui-Gon'
            ]
        }, {
            category: 'Mastered',
            students: [
              'John',
              'Katie'
            ]
        }];
```

I want to add more such bars as one below another with some text beside it but I am failing. Bars like below.

[image]

Code of the same is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/uG1OGO57g4Nad5d0m3Lm?p=preview

The width of the block should be the number of students under the category. and when hover on the bar it should display like this:

[image]

What I have tried so far is [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/70864r68/1/)

which is not desirable.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit 2: I need this:

[image]

which is nothing but one bar showing the 5 categories each. Categories are: Struggling, Level one, Level Two, Level Three, and Mastered. Each category should represent unique color. And the number of students appearing under that category should appear as number. Rest of the animation part when hovered is already done.

Comment: Would you mind sketching out what you're trying to archieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve more than one bar of figure1 type .

Comment: Sorry but this isn't helping much. You mean you want multiple same looking bars stacked on top of each other?

Comment: Yes same looking but different data and some texts beside them  ; say if two bars are there then text for them is say " bar1" and "bar2". I am not getting how to modify that data used in the code and corresponding code.

Comment: Please do a graphical sketch and post an image here

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, I have put a sketch in edited question, please see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99873/discussion-between-artiga-and-hubert-grzeskowiak).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague so I'll just shot into the dark. Is this what you're looking for? https://fiddle.jshell.net/70864r68/17/

Changed JS:

```
var student_data = [{
        classes:'class1',
        category: 'Struggling',
        students: [
          'Ben',
        ]
    }, 
    {
        classes:'class1',
        category: 'Struggling',
        students: []
    },
    {
        classes:'class1',
        category: 'Struggling',
        students: [
          'Ben',
          'Elizabeth'
        ]
    },{
        classes: 'class1',
        category: 'Level One',
        students: [
          'Jessica',
          'Matt'
        ]
    },
    {
        classes: 'class1',
        category: 'Level Two',
        students: [
          'Luke',
          'Leia',
          'Han',
          'Chewbaca'
        ]
    },
    {
        classes: 'class1',
        category: 'Level Three',
        students: [
          'Obi-one',
          'Qui-Gon'
        ]
    }, {
        classes: 'class1',
        category: 'Mastered',
        students: [
          'John',
          'Katie'
        ]
    }, {
        classes: 'class2',
        category: 'Struggling',
    students: [
      'Benten',
      'Elizabeth Hurly',
      'Obi wan Kenobi'
    ]
    }, {
        classes: 'class2',
        category: 'Level One',
        students: [
          'Jessica simpson',
          'Matt Demon'
        ]
    },
    {
    classes: 'class2',
        category: 'Level Two',
    students: [
      'Liam',
      'Leisa',
      'Huston',
      'Chan'
    ]
    },
    {
        classes: 'class2',
        category: 'Level Three',
        students: [
          'Orlando',
          'Quintoon Terento'
        ]
    }, {
    classes: 'class2',
        category: 'Mastered',
    students: [
      'Johny',
      'Kate'
    ]
    }];

    // the quantile scale maps an input domain of
        // values to an output range of values by 'spreading'
        // the domain across the range.
    var colors = d3.scale.quantile()
          .domain([0, 5])
          .range(['red', 'grey', 'lightblue', 'darkblue', 'pink', 'green']);

    for (var i = 0; i < student_data.length; i++) {
        // the base element
        var root = d3.select('.panel');

        // selectAll ~= querySelectorAll
        // says, find all elements with class 'category'
        // if none exist, prepare a selection of
        // student_data.length elements
        var display = root.selectAll('.category')
          .data(student_data);

        // take the prepared selection and
        // for each
        display.enter()
          // create an element
          .append('div')
          // assign the 'category' class to the element
          .attr('class', 'category')
          // set the background color
          .style('background-color', function (d, i) {
              // d is the current array element of student_data
              // i is the index of the current array element of student_data
              // so, pass i to the colors scale/map to get back a color
              return colors(d.students.length);
          })
          .style('padding-right', function(d, i) {
            return 1 + d.students.length + "rem";
          })
          // add a mouse enter handler to set the text of a
          // yet to be added label.
          .on('mouseenter', function (d) {
              // this is the current element
              d3.select(this)
                // so, select the first element
                // with class label
                .select('.label')
                // and set it's text to the category property
                // of current array element of student_data
                .text(d.category);
          })
          // add a mouse leave handler to reset the text of the still
          // yet to be added label.
          .on('mouseleave', function (d) {
              d3.select(this).select('.label').text(d.students.length);
          })
          // for each created element
          .each(function (d) {
              // select the current element
              var selection = d3.select(this);
              // create the label referenced above
              var label = selection.append('div')
                // assign it a class of 'label'
                .attr('class', 'label')
                // and set it's text to count of
                // the students property
                .text(function (d) {
                    // d = student_data[i]
                    return d.students.length;
                });
              // also, prepare a new selection of
              // elements for each of the student names
              var names = selection
                .selectAll('.student')
                .data(d.students);
              // take the prepared selection and
              // for each
              names.enter()
                // create an element
                .append('div')
                // assign the 'student' class
                .attr('class', 'student')
                // and set the text to that
                // of the current element
                .text(function (dd) {
                    // dd = student_data[i].students[j]
                    return dd;
                });
          });
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I need the same solution but with 5 blocks representing one bar . can you please  break the whole var into 2 bars?

Comment: 5 blocks representing one bar? Like how? Please describe your desired end result as detailed as possible or we'll shoot into the dark the whole time.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Hubert, I ll try to sketch my desired result and will edit my question accordingly.